# Mask_RCNN. Train Ballon.py error: OOM when allocating tensor with shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, object-detection

Hey i have followed the tutorial on object detection with Mask RCNN tensorflow on:[Mask RCNN github](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN)
Hey when i run the Ballon.py train command" python balloon.py train --dataset=balloon1 --weights=coco" in command prompt to train the balloon dataset i get the following error:
[Command prompt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhF5s.png)
I have tried to change some variables in the "Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\config.py" file but i still get the error. Have anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: You are running out of memory. Change the batch size or increase the memory

Comment: Hey i have the following Configurations: https://imgur.com/a/oxE1nto . But i still get this error : https://imgur.com/a/tIzPapp .

Comment: Can i change something by dedicating more to my video memory: (https://imgur.com/fx5goGh)